# Holomorphic function - Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Good evening to everybody! I was reading John Conway's book on complex analysis of one variable, and I was trying to understand the proof of Cauchy's integral formula. In the proof he uses an argument, which he leaves as an exercise. More specifically:

Let $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function, where $G$ is an open set. For a fixed $w\in G$ we define the following function: $h: G\to \mathbb{C}$, where $h(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$ if $z\neq w$, and $h(w)=f'(w)$. The author says that this function is analytic on $G$. I already checked the continuity on $G$ and the analyticity on $G\backslash \{w \}$ but how can one prove that $h$ is analytic also at the point $w$ ?? Any ideas would be really thankful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that $w$ is a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem) for the function $h$.

Edit: We can use the limit definition of the derivative to explicitly  show the derivative of $h$ at $w$ exists: 
$$h'(w) := \lim_{z \to w} \frac{h(z) - h(w)}{z - w} = \lim_{z \to w} \left(\frac{\frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z - w} - f'(w)}{z - w} \right) = \lim_{z \to w} \frac{f(z) - f(w) - f'(w)(z - w)}{(z - w)^2}.$$
We can use that $f$ is analytic to evaluate this limit. What about the higher derivatives of $h$?

Comment: Hello! Hm, this proof is presented on a chapter which is before the singularities. So I guess there must be some different proof.

Comment: I edited the post with an approach not needing Riemann's theorem on removable singularities---although it's a useful one to know!

Comment: Ok,I had reached also at the same point, but didn't think to apply the power series expansion of $f$ around the point $w$. It makes sense now, since the terms at the enumerator are the first two terms of the expansion, so if we divide by $(z-w)^2$ and then take the limit, it equals $f''(w)/2$. Thanks a lot Sam Freedman !